# How can I speed up Docker's slow "build" process?

Tags: docker

For example,

```
#!/bin/bash
touch a b c d
docker pull alpine
# This SHOULD take the fraction of a second only
docker build --no-cache -t test -f - . <<EOF
FROM alpine
COPY a /
COPY b /tmp
COPY c /var
COPY d /etc
EOF
```

This is a basic `docker build` command which adds four empty files to the image. Each COPY step takes about one second. Especially for manual testing, this is annoying. It is not *very* slow, but I do not understand the reason for the unnecessary waiting time.

Why, and how can I speed this up?

Comment: What is the CPU and memory on your host?

Comment: @BlackFrog plenty, modern system 4x3,5 GHz 16 GB ram

Comment: Are there other files beside `a b c d` in that directory? If yes, they are part of the build process, too, although not needed.

Comment: @mviereck no, directoy is empty.  So is it just my machine and for you, the above works almost instantly?

Comment: @Blauhirn Takes about 1.5s here. Without COPY instructions about 0.3s. (Measured with `time docker ...`).

Comment: @mviereck 1.2s for adding 4 empty files is still insanely much. The time difference is strange however.

Comment: Each `COPY` command creates a new [layer](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices), so it isn't just _adding 4 empty files_.

Comment: @bartolo-otrit Right... but since `alpine` is only 5.6 MB in size, the layer creation length of 1 second is still note really justified